# D3 area chart not rendering end to end

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

[my area chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf3XK.jpg) I've used the example for an area chart: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195 and changed the data. Instead of using time values on the x-axis, I changed the values to strings and used the domain function `x.domain( data.map( function(d) { return d.xvalue; } ) );` with the scale function `var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width])`. Two problems with this: 1. The values on the x axis are not in sync with the area values (highs and lows). 2. The area is not covering the entire width of the svg. My understanding of scaleBand is it takes in string values and places them on the x axis at equal distances. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance..

```js
var margin = {
  top: 40,
  right: 5,
  bottom: 25,
  left: 35
};
var width = 980 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom),
  g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "chartBoxg").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// gridlines in x axis function
function make_x_gridlines() {
  return d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(0)
}

// gridlines in y axis function
function make_y_gridlines() {
  return d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(5)
}
var portavgValue;
console.log(portavgValue);
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.xvalue);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.portalAvg);
  });

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var failRateArea = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.xvalue);
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d.failrate);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom);

var successrateArea = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.xvalue);
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d.successRate);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom);
//defining tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "acadMetrictooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) {

  d.failrate = +d.failrate;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.xvalue;
  }));
  y.domain([0, 100]).nice();

  failRateArea.y0(y(0));
  successrateArea.y0(y(0));

  // add the Y gridlines
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "Ygrid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(make_y_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-width)
      .tickFormat("")
    )

  // add the X gridlines
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "Xgrid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-height)
      .tickFormat("")
    )




  g.append("g").attr("class", "sucRateBox")
    .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "#bdf4e1")
    .style("opacity", "0.9")
    .attr("d", successrateArea);

  g.append("g").attr("class", "failRateBox")
    .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "#d0aa9d")
    .style("opacity", "0.9")
    .attr("d", failRateArea);



  g.append("g").attr("class", "axisX")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("fill", "#6d6d6d")
    .style("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)");

  g.append("g").attr("class", "axisY")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSizeOuter(0).tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d + "%"
    }))





});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a band scale here: band scales have associated bandwidths.

Instead on that, use a point scale:

```
var x = d3.scalePoint()
   .rangeRound([0, width]);
```

Comment: Thank you Gerardo! Using scalePoint fixed both the problems. Thanks again for clearing the confusion between scaleBand and scalePoint..